# Search based on DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm relatively new to ruby on rails. I do have a custom search form where I want to search with date and time. My database table does have a column with datetime as a datatype. I knew that we can extract date from Date(column name). I would like to know how to extract only time from datetime field. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [`date_format`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

```
mysql> select id, created_at from users limit 1;
+----+---------------------+
| id | created_at          |
+----+---------------------+
|  8 | 2009-08-19 09:24:24 |
+----+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%h/%i/%s") from users limit 1;
+----+-------------------------------------+
| id | DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%h/%i/%s") |
+----+-------------------------------------+
|  8 | 09/24/24                            |
```